# Постепенное отображение подгружаемых данных Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, steam-web-api, steam

**Laravel 5.3**

**Steam API**

**Ajax**

При вводе в input идет аджакс запрос, который использует Steam API для подбора возможных вариантов поиска ( живой поиск ).

Однако, слишком долго.
Пользователь ввел **к примеру** Half, и надо **ждать 15-30 секунд** пока соберет все результаты где есть ключевое слово и потом только выведет.

**Как сделать вывод сразу того, что ajax находит?**

```
function getSteamGames(event) {
        $('.suggested').html('');
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
        gameName = $('#gameName').val();
        if(gameName.length >= 4)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getsteamgames',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'gameName': gameName,
                    '_token': token,
                },
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    var  gameName = element.name,
                    appID = element.appid;
                    $('.suggested').prepend('<div class="suggestedGame label label-info" data-tag_id="'+appID+'">' + gameName + '</div>');

                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("ERROR");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: а Steam API у вас на сервере? так как ваш код на js - это не поддерживает. если вы используете чистый jQuery, то done будет ждать завершения запроса и в конце вы получить все данные сразу.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  у меня OpenServer. Все данные получаю по их API, с их серверов, потом на своем обрабатываю, и уже вывожу. Тут какраз обращение идет к ним, потом обработка,и вернет уже то что надо, но вывод долгий, хотелось бы показать пользователю что все ОК, что все работает, только грузит долго, данных ведь у них много, и скорость интернета влияет.

Comment: так показывайте Spinner, что то типа - идет загрузка.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  да, тоже вариант, хотя интерактивности меньше :(

Comment: @MikhailVaysman так можно ли как-то отображать постепенно результаты которые грузит, нашло 10 совпадение, отобразило и ищет дальше?

Comment: можно, но надо ставить плагин к jQuery или использовать другую библиотеку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве spinner - надпись

```
function getSteamGames(event) {
  $('.suggested').html('');
  var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
    gameName = $('#gameName').val();
  if(gameName.length >= 4) {
    // показали спиннер
    $('.suggested').html('Загрузка данных...');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/getsteamgames',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'gameName': gameName,
        '_token': token,
      },
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
          var  gameName = element.name,
            appID = element.appid;
          // убрали спиннер
          $('.suggested').html('');
          $('.suggested').prepend('<div class="suggestedGame label label-info" data-tag_id="'+appID+'">' + gameName + '</div>');

        });
      })
      .fail(function() {
        // показали ошибку
        $('.suggested').html('Произошла ошибка при загрузки данных');
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: хотя это не то что я хотел, думаю подойдет такое для начала. Ведь лучше хоть что-то :) 

Спасибо, кстати, вы говорили про какие-то библиотеки которые позволяют такое сделтаь, может порекомендуете что? :)

Comment: я сам не использовал такой подход. я делал подобное на websocket.